# Returning Reference from function of pointer type

Tags: c++11, pointers, reference

Was told today that this was a "clever way of making something like a constructor" but it "sews the seeds of destruction" even though it works. I've been searching and I can't seem to figure out why. Thanks.

```
Person* makePerson(std::string name, std::int num) {
    Person p(name, num);
    return &p;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning a pointer to a variable whose lifetime is over when the function returns.  This is useless and will lead to undefined behavior.

You want something like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<Person> makePerson(std::string name, std::int num) {
    std::unique_ptr<Person> p(new Person(name, num));
    return std::move(p);
}
```

P.S.: Use `int` not `std::int`.